# Get specific data from a webpage with HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to get data from a webpage in C# using the HTML Agility Pack. 
I have been able to retrieve data from different webpage, but on this webpage I am getting a `NullReferenceException` and my only guess is that it has something to do with the XPath.

Here is my code, trying to reach the 'Limbo Wand' text

```
string url = "https://www.dofus.com/en/mmorpg/encyclopedia/weapons/180-limbo-wand";
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = htmlWeb.Load(url);

string weaponName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/h1/text()")[0].InnerText; // <-- NullReferenceException here
```

Removing the `text()`in my XPath doesn't work, and even trying to get the text from `/html/head/title` doesn't work.

Is there anything wrong with my XPath ? Or is it a problem with the webpage that HTML Agility Pack can't use it properly ?

Thank you in advance to anyone who may be able to give me some hints!

Comment: Did you check the raw html of `doc`, because your XPath looks correct? It's most likely that there's content generated using javascript and thus the html doesn't match. Looking at the site it's responsive and that could be a problem. I don't entirely know the internals of HtmlAgilityPack, but I believe it's just taking the raw html and parses it, so dynamic content generated by javascript won't show.

Comment: That's the message I got in `DocumentNode`: _"Attention Required! | Cloudflare [...] Please enable cookies. [...] Please complete the security check to access dofus.com [...] Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA? [...] "_

Comment: Does that mean there is a CAPTCHA to complete and therefore it doesn't load the webpage correctly thus giving me the `NullReferenceException` ?

Comment: Yes there's some kind of protection, probably from Cloudfare, so the webpage is not loaded. You can search: "html agility pack cloudfare" and you'll get an idea of the problem and maybe find a solution. Maybe you can try this code: [Cloudflare http handler](https://gist.github.com/fmj02/65a4a97a9f29654945fc16fc703328de)

Answer (score 1):

HtmlWeb is just shit for fetching the source of a site. Mostly because it doesn't handle redirects. But I am not sure that is the underlying problem here. Use a Web request instead. like so:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
try
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.dofus.com/en/mmorpg/encyclopedia/weapons/180-limbo-wand");
    request.Method = "GET";

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            doc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

After this you have a HtmlDocument. And you can easily get the title like so(since there is only one title tag):

```
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/title")[0].InnerText);
```

Now to get the weapon name using the most simple and easy xpath would be like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='ak-return-link']").InnerText.Trim());
```

The Trim() at the end is just to remove the whitespace at the start and end of the string.